# Python script/Google API (PDF exporter) - Intermittently only picks up 1 file of many

Tags: python, import, google-api

we are currently using a Python script (3.11.0) via Google API to pick up just PDFs from a group mailbox and copy them over into a shared folder, which another application scans and then imports.  The script executes daily at 11pm via Windows Task Manager and just looks at email from that day.
Script run status and output is logged through Event Viewer, so we can see what it has picked up and moved to the file share, plus a log from the application that shows what it imported.

For the most part it's been working fine, however this week I had a team member come to me to advise they've noted that we seem to be missing import files from a particular sender from at least the past 2 months.

I investigated and found that they were correct; Every email from this particular sender that had more than 1 PDF file attached only imported the one file.  We use this system for invoice importing so it was a little worrying, so I checked the last few days worth and found that intermittently it was doing the same thing to multiple other emails coming in.  Last night I attached 3 PDFs that had failed to import from the initial investigation and emailed them in from my own email address to the group mailbox.  Checked the script output this morning and all 3 were picked up from the same email with no issues.  Looking through yesterdays mailbox and cross referencing against the picked up files shown in event viewer confirmed that it was still intermittently ignoring PDFs.

I honestly don't know if its a source issue (something in the emails making it looks like 1 data file not several?) or our script is being weird.  This is my very first script and it was adapted by a colleague with input from us, by they have since left.  I've looked through the code and it looks OK, set to look for PDFs only, deal with duplicates etc.  There is a section on message ID's and parts, and it could be something to do with it but we are not doing anything special there.

Here's the code, only bit I've cleared is the location of the target folder.  If anyone has heard of this before or sees anything in this code, do let me know.

-----

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import base64
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

import sys
import win32evtlogutil
import win32evtlog

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    targetFolder="*****"
    #windows log that the script has been run
    appName='Gmail Downloader'
    eventCategory=0
    data=None
    sid=None
    
    createLogEntry(appName,0,eventCategory,win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,['script executed'],data,sid)
    

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        #get messages with attachments from the last day
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q="has:attachment newer_than:1d filename:pdf", maxResults=500).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        
        if not messages:
            createLogEntry(appName,0,eventCategory,win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,['no mail found'],data,sid)
            return
        
        #get message IDs
        attachment_list=[]
        for message in messages:
            msg_id=message['id']
            filename=None
            att_id=None

            try:
                message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id).execute()

                if 'parts' not in message['payload']:
                    message['payload']['parts']=[]
                    message['payload']['parts'].append(message['payload'])

                for part in message['payload']['parts']:
                    
                    #some extra checking for if the part is multipart and the attachment ID is within a part of this part. i know that makes no sense
                    if 'parts' in part:
                        for part2 in part['parts']:
                            if part2['filename']:
                                
                                att_id=part2['body']['attachmentId']
                                filename=part2['filename']


                    #track an instance number in case of duplicate pdf names
                    file_version_number=1
                    if part['filename']:
                        
                        filename=part['filename']
                        if 'data' in part['body']:
                            data = part['body']['data']
                        else:
                            att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
                            
                            

                    if filename and att_id:
                        # this will return a tuple of root and extension
                        split_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)
                        if split_filename[1].lower()==".pdf":

                            att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId=msg_id,id=att_id).execute()
                            data = att['data']

                            #replace any / and : in file names as it breaks the file write
                            filename=filename.replace('/','_')
                            filename=filename.replace(':','-')
                            file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
                            path = targetFolder+filename

                            #check if file exists. if it does, increment the file name by 1
                            while(os.path.exists(path)):
                                path=targetFolder+str(file_version_number)+"_"+filename
                                file_version_number+=1

                            with open(path, 'bw+') as f:
                                
                                f.write(file_data)   

                            attachment_list.append(filename)

            except HttpError as error:
                createLogEntry(appName,0,0,win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,['http error'],None,None)


    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print('httpError')

    #log the downloaded mail
    if len(attachment_list)>0:
        createLogEntry(appName,0,0,win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,attachment_list,None,None)
    else:
        createLogEntry(appName,0,0,win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,['no attachments found'],None,None)

def createLogEntry(appName,eventID,eventCategory,eventType,strings,data,sid):
    win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(appName,eventID,eventCategory,eventType,strings,data,sid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've got an update to this one, found quite by accident.   I've been going back through emails and it's definitely picking on certain senders, so as part of the checks I was looking at one particular day.  In Gmail there are filters you can apply to help your search so I did one for the sender I was interested in, then applied the 'Has attachment' filter.  All good so far, I could see the emails I wanted, but wanted to clean it up so then clicked on the 'PDF' option that you get that linked to the 'has attachment' tag.  Guess what happened... all of my emails vanished! Untag, returned..